# Python: Does key exist in dictionary (Python 3.1)

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

```
arguments=dict()
if (arg.find("--help") == 0):
  arguments["help"] = 1
if help in arguments:
  #this doesnt work

print(arguments["help"]) # This will print 1
```

Cannot find out if a certain key has been defined. .has_key has been deprecated in 2.7 and I haven't find other solution than this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're parsing arguments why not just use `optparse`? (http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)

Comment: optparse has been replaced by argparse, which will be maintained in future versions of Python (though at the moment I don't think there are very substantial differences).  I believe it's supported by 2.7+ and 3.2+.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do `"help" in arguments`.

```
>>> arguments = dict()
>>> arguments["help"]=1
>>> "help" in arguments
True
```

In your example you have written `help in arguments` without quotes around the string. Hence it assumes to ask whether the built-in function `help` is a key in your dictionary.

Also notice that you can write `arguments = {}` as a more pythonic way of creating a dict.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the quotes around help.  Because help is a builtin, python isn't complaining like it normally would.